# Eclipse project became invisible in file explorer after pushing to github

Tags: eclipse, macos, github

I just successfully pushed an eclipse project to github. What's weird is I can't see the project in my file explorer anymore. But I can still see the project through eclipse and on github.

I followed the first answer from this question on Quora when pushing my project. https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-export-the-project-in-Eclipse-to-a-GitHub-repository

**The screenshot of my eclipse**

[image: The screenshot of my eclipse]

**The file explorer showing the same path**

[image: The file explorer showing the same path]

Answer (score 1):

When you put your project in a local Git repository the project files are moved out of the workspace in to the Git repository.

Eclipse just keeps a pointer to the project in the workspace metadata. You can see this by looking at the project Properties > Resource page - look at the 'Location' field.